# Can we substitute values after analytic continuation

Tags: dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation

**Motivating example:**

Consider the following $f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}A_n(z)$, and $g(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} B_n(z)$.

Lets say $A_n(z)=\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^z}$ and $ B_n(z)=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)^z}$

Then $f(z)=\beta(z)$ would be the Dirichlet beta and $g(z)=\eta(z)$ would be the Dirichlet eta function.

Let's say we KNOW what the values of $\eta(z)$ are after analytic continuation. $\eta(-1)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\eta(0)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Now writing $\beta(-1)$ as its summation form would be nonsense, but if we were to, it would give us $$\beta(-1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(2n+1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[2(n+1)(-1)^n-(-1)^n]=2{\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{-1}}}_{\eta(-1)}}-{\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^0}}_{\eta(0)}}=\frac{2}{4}-\frac{1}{2}=0$$

Which is the correct value of $\beta(-1)$.

I have encountered these quite a few times, where I am computing the analytic continuation of a function and I spot another function appearing where I know the value of it, the answer turns out to be correct when I use this technique.  Therefore I would like to show the following :

**Proposition**

let $f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}A_n(z)$, and $g(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} B_n(z)$.

If $g(z)$ has an analytic continuation on the neighbourhood of $z_i$ where $g(z_i)=w_i$.

If we have that $A_n(\alpha_0)=L(B_n(z_0),B_n(z_1),...,B_n(z_k))$ where $L$ is a linear function, then

$$f(\alpha_0)=L(g(z_0),...,g(z_k))$$

,

In our example previously. $L(x,y)=2x-y$

**Proof**

$$A_n(\alpha_0)=L(B_n(z_0),B_n(z_1),...,B_n(z_k))$$
$$\Rightarrow A_n(\alpha_0)-L(B_n(z_0),B_n(z_1),...,B_n(z_k))=0$$
\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[A_n(\alpha_0)-L(B_n(z_0),B_n(z_1),...,B_n(z_k))\right]=0
\end{equation}
$$f(\alpha_0)-L(g(z_0),...,g(z_k))\overset{(?)}{=}0$$

I am not sure if the third line to the fourth line is correct. $\alpha_0$ is a point whilst doing analytic continuation we should consider an open set. And notice that the linearity of the function $L$ depends on $\alpha_0$. $L$ would not be linear if $\alpha_0=\frac{1}{2}$ (say). As in our example, we can only expand $A_n(z)$ when $z$ is a non-positive integer, which we cannot do analytic continuation on (the set of non-positive integers is discrete).

Maybe we can define a function $C_n(\alpha_0,z_0,...,z_k)=A_n(\alpha_0)-L(B_n(z_0),B_n(z_1),...,B_n(z_k))$ and investigate $\sum C_n$? I am not sure how to proceede.

Any help is greatly appreciated.